# How to pass O.S. from a disk to another

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems

I bought a SSD and I wanted to use my operating system on it and use other disks to store other data. Problem is that this is an upgrade and my PC is already running with O.S. in one HDD. My question is if its possible to switch the O.S. data from the HDD to the SSD without having to format, because I already have too much data stored, if so how? And if not what other solutions I have?

Comment: OS is ? Can you boot from live OS in CD/USB ? Do you prefer a solution based on Linux or Windows ?

Answer (score 3):

Some SSDs include software which will carry out this process for you. If yours does, I would recommend using it as it often is the most reliable way to migrate a system. I have used the Samsung migration tool in the past with no issues at all.

If you don't have a manufacturer provided tool to do this, there are a few ways to migrate the system.

If you're new SSD is big enough to hold the entire content of your existing disk, this this is very possible.

The exact process varies though depending on a number of factors.

1. If you are using a laptop, you need to connect the SSD to an external port. Many SSDs include USB cables for this purpose, but if you don't have one you will need to source one from somewhere.
2. What OS are you using. Copying a disk to another disk is different on Windows, MacOS, and Linux, and the specific instructions are quite different in each case.
3. What file system you are using, and what partition scheme. Much like with the OS, the partition scheme and file systems employed in the three OS's mentioned all have their own specific requirements for duplicating them.

The duplication process differs depending on how you go about it, but in short there are two real ways this works.

1. You format the SSD, make it bootable, then copy all the data from your hard disk to the new partition. This is the most involved method, and is best applied when you're moving data from one disk to a smaller disk. If you have a 500Gb hard drive and you're migrating to a 250Gb SSD, so long as you have less than 250Gb of data to move, it will work fine. 
   I have personally used this process in the past as it is the most flexible, but it's not the most straightforward process on Windows.
2. You clone the whole disk to the new one, boot sector, file system and all. This approach is often most successful as it can be done in one operation, although because it's just grabbing the block data from the disk and copying it, it can sometimes lead to data corruption which goes unnoticed during the process and doesn't show up until much later - I add that as a note of caution, but in practice it's pretty unlikely now that SSDs are well established and very reliable.

***If you are running windows***,  check the following link. It will talk you through the whole process, but I will add a note of caution - Read it ALL FIRST.... TWICE. I cannot emphasise enough how critical knowing each step of the process before hand is to reduce the risk of wiping your existing data.

http://www.lifehacker.co.uk/2014/06/02/migrate-solid-state-drive-without-reinstalling-windows

***If you are running MacOS***, the following link will talk you through the process. This is slightly more involved and the Windows process as it requires more manual steps, however as with any data migration, so long as you read the whole thing before hand and get the plan straight in your head before you start, it's not overly difficult

https://eshop.macsales.com/articles/how-to-transfer-your-data-from-your-old-drive-to-a-new-drive

I would advise that you take a backup on to an external disk before hand. If you don't have a backup solution in place at the moment, I suggest borrowing a USB disk from someone to back up everything before you start.

Comment: So Kingston has already a software that can help me with that?

Comment: My apologies, I used Ranish partition manager for cloning to a kingston disk. The Kingston tool is for monitoring the health of the disk, rather than for duplicating data. It's been a long while since I cloned to a Kingston SSD, and after re-reading my notes from the last one, I spotted my error. I have amended my answer to reflect this. For cloning to a Kingston disk, this guide should help. https://www.backup-utility.com/clone/clone-hdd-to-kingston-ssd-3889.html